# JSON to Pandas Dataframe not knowing if JSON will have all the columns of the dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am doing a research project and trying to pull thousands of quarterly results for companies from the SEC EDGAR API.

Each result is a list of dictionaries structured as follows:

```
[{'field': 'othercurrentliabilities', 'value': 6886000000.0},
 {'field': 'otherliabilities', 'value': 13700000000.0},
 {'field': 'propertyplantequipmentnet', 'value': 15789000000.0}...]
```

I want each result to be a row of a pandas dataframe. The issue is that each result may not have the same fields due to the data available. I would like to check if the column(field) of the dataframe is present in one of the results  field and if it is add the result value to the row. If not, I would like to add an `np.NaN`. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

A list/dict comprehension ought to work here:

```
In [11]: s
Out[11]:
[[{'field': 'othercurrentliabilities', 'value': 6886000000.0},
  {'field': 'otherliabilities', 'value': 13700000000.0},
  {'field': 'propertyplantequipmentnet', 'value': 15789000000.0}],
 [{'field': 'othercurrentliabilities', 'value': 6886000000.0}]]

In [12]: pd.DataFrame([{d["field"]: d["value"] for d in row} for row in s])
Out[12]:
   othercurrentliabilities  otherliabilities  propertyplantequipmentnet
0             6.886000e+09      1.370000e+10               1.578900e+10
1             6.886000e+09               NaN                        NaN
```

Comment: Thank you! This is giving me an error 'list' object has no attribute '_convert_slice_indexer'-do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @RyanFrancisCashMiller notice mine is a list of rows (a list of lists), it needs to make a DataFrame so as it's a list of rows. If it's a single list, do you need to split it into chunks somehow (how do you know when a new row starts)?

Answer (score -1):

make a list of df.result.rows[x]['values']
like below

```
s=[]
```

for x in range(df.result.totalrows[0]):
    s=s+[df.result.rows[x]['values']]
    print(x)

df1=pd.DataFrame([{d["field"]: d["value"] for d in row} for row in s]

df1

will give you result.